# Cordova inappbrowser not working when build in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, inappbrowser

Since 30th of april Apple does not allow apps build with SDK lower than 13. Ive used to build my apps using Phonegap build (https://build.phonegap.com/) but it uses SDK 12. Now im trying to build my apps using Xcode.

Every build i do using Phonegap build and using a test distribution profile to install this build on my phone works like a charm but when i build the app using the same config.xml as i use for my Phonegap build the inappbrowser is not working anymore.

I think it has something to do with the UIWebView being depricated as of SKD 13. Therefor ive used the tutorials provided by Cordova to implement the WkWebview.

I've tried removing all plugins except wkwebview-engine and inappbrowser but this has no effect.

- Cordova CLI 9.0.0
- inappbrowser 3.2.0
- wkwebview-engine 1.2.1
- ios platform add 5.1.1

My config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.app.name" version="0.2.13" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <name>appname</name>
  <description>
  </description>
  <author email="mymail" href="mywebsite">
    my name
  </author>
  <content src="dist/index.html"/>
  <platform name="ios"/>
  <platform name="android"/>
  <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
  <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-9.0.0"/>
  <preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
  <preference name="target-device" value="universal"/>
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true"/>
  <preference name="detect-data-types" value="false"/>
  <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/>
  <preference name="deployment-target" value="7.0"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false"/>
  <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque"/>
  <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true"/>
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19"/>
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28"/>
  <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
  <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="stateVisible|adjustResize"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="0"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false"/>
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
      <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"/>
    </edit-config>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false"/>
  </platform>  
  <access origin="*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="*://*youtube.com"/>
  <access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="true"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" launch-external="yes"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
    <allow-navigation href="mailto:*" launch-external="yes"/>
  </platform>
  <feature name="TouchID">
    <param name="ios-package" value="TouchID"/>
  </feature>
  <platform name="ios">
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
    <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
  </platform>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="3.2.0" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" spec="1.2.1" />
</widget>
```

before testing i do this to make sure all plugins are installed fresh:

```
rm -rf package-lock.json package.json platforms plugins/* node_modules
cordova platform add ios@5.1.1
```

i receive no response in the xcode console just this information when build is finished:

```
2020-05-13 16:23:33.805959+0200 App[7410:670156] [Accessibility] ****************** Loading GAX Client Bundle ****************
2020-05-13 16:23:33.996820+0200 App[7410:670156] Apache Cordova native platform version 5.1.1 is starting.
2020-05-13 16:23:33.998789+0200 App[7410:670156] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2020-05-13 16:23:34.016143+0200 App[7410:670156] 

Started backup to iCloud! Please be careful.
Your application might be rejected by Apple if you store too much data.
For more information please read "iOS Data Storage Guidelines" at:
https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/
To disable web storage backup to iCloud, set the BackupWebStorage preference to "local" in the Cordova config.xml file
2020-05-13 16:23:34.282716+0200 App[7410:670156] CDVWKWebViewEngine will reload WKWebView if required on resume
2020-05-13 16:23:34.283306+0200 App[7410:670156] Using WKWebView
2020-05-13 16:23:34.284438+0200 App[7410:670156] [CDVTimer][console] 0.174999ms
2020-05-13 16:23:34.285355+0200 App[7410:670156] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.338078ms
2020-05-13 16:23:34.290426+0200 App[7410:670156] Unlimited access to network resources
2020-05-13 16:23:34.291285+0200 App[7410:670156] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 5.457997ms
2020-05-13 16:23:34.292067+0200 App[7410:670156] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.302076ms
2020-05-13 16:23:34.292696+0200 App[7410:670156] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 8.646965ms
```

I'm out of ideas to fix this. maybe anyone has some fresh look so i can try some new things.

Comment: I'm sorry forgot to show how i do the call for the inappbrowser
`<v-list-item v-bind:onclick="'window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open(\''+generalSettings[facebook]+'\',\'_blank\',\'usewkwebview=yes,location=no,hideurlbar=true,toolbarcolor=#78A13F,closebuttoncolor=#ffffff,closebuttoncaption='+$t('inappbrowser.close')+'\'); return false;'">`

Answer (score 0):

Well managed to find the answer. My file structure was www/dist/index.html and in there was the link to cordova.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

it needed to be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../cordova.js"></script>
```

besides that, during the command:

```
cordova platform add ios@5.1.1
```

there were some yellow messages for example:

```
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-inappbrowser': Error: Cannot find module 'glob'
```

I was ignoring them because well... yellow

after some research i came across the solution for this. after the messages execute:

```
cordova platform rm ios
```

And then again:

```
cordova platform add ios@5.1.1
```

the second time the plugins are installed successfully and this time the inappbrowser works again.

for now this is a workaraound, the question im still having is why i get the Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-inappbrowser': Error: Cannot find module 'glob'messages when adding the platform for the first time..?